Is there a way to find reason of Android reboot?
I've OnePlus 9 Pro with Android 13. The phone is rooted and has a custom ROM, but my issue isn't common for that ROM. The Phone generally works well, however at least once or twice a day it suffers random reboots. Sometimes it's during a call, sometimes when browsing the internet, and sometimes I spot the phone rebooting while lying on the desk, so the issue is not related to a particular task.
I haven't updated my ROM for a while, I'll do it today, however, the problem did persist through updates earlier. It has that annoying habit since I've installed crDroid, it didn't have so on stock rooted firmware. I've flashed it strictly by the manual of ROM developers - from stock firmware to crDroid, all updates were installed after upgrading firmware, as it was mentioned by the devs of ROM, so I think that it must be one of randomly crashing apps.
I know about logcat, but it definitely has too many lines to find anything out of it (another thing that I'm not sure about is if it persists through a reboot).
So, I was wondering, if it's possible, how to find out a particular reason for such a random reboot. Is there any event log in Android, or someone could recommend such an app? Is there any other source of knowledge in Android or a Magisk module to log such things?
